# How to use environment variable to avoid hard-coding postgresql's username and password in database.yml?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I created a new Rails app called sample_app and I use postgresql as my db (I already created a postgresql username and password). I use this setup guide https://gorails.com/setup/ubuntu/16.04

So I run this command `rails new sample_app -d postgresql`. And then I have to edit the `config/database.yml` to match the username and password to my postgresql's username and password I just created. But I don't want to hard-code because I will be using git.

I found this tutorial from digital ocean which suggest to use:

```
username: <%= ENV['APPNAME_DATABASE_USER'] %>
password: <%= ENV['APPNAME_DATABASE_PASSWORD'] %>
```

Is this the correct code? If so, since my app is called sample_app, my code should be?

```
username: <%= ENV['SAMPLE_APP_DATABASE_USER'] %>
password: <%= ENV['SAMPLE_APP_DATABASE_PASSWORD'] %>
```

If this is not the correct one, can you help me? Thank you!

Comment: you can take any name for that,

Comment: can you expland? I don't understand what you mean, I'm really a newbie.

Comment: added an answer on how to set environment variables. pls check once.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There are many ways you can set the environment variables.

Here are two of them,

**Option One: Setting ENV variables via a yml file**

Create a file `config/local_env.yml`:

**config/local_env.yml:**

```
SAMPLE_APP_DATABASE_USER: 'your username'
SAMPLE_APP_DATABASE_PASSWORD: '******'
```

The above are the names you will use like,**`ENV['SAMPLE_APP_DATABASE_USER']`**. **these can be names as your wish**. you can take any name, but **we should use the same name in the ENV reference**.

**add it to gitignore:**

`/config/local_env.yml`

Change some code in `application.rb`

**application.rb:**

```
config.before_configuration do
  env_file = File.join(Rails.root, 'config', 'local_env.yml')
  YAML.load(File.open(env_file)).each do |key, value|
    ENV[key.to_s] = value
  end if File.exists?(env_file)
end
```

**The code opens the config/local_env.yml file, reads each key/value pair, and sets environment variables.**

**Using Environment Variables:**

```
username: <%= ENV['SAMPLE_APP_DATABASE_USER'] %>
password: <%= ENV['SAMPLE_APP_DATABASE_PASSWORD'] %>
```

---

**Option Two: Use the Figaro Gem**

The gem takes advantage of Ruby’s ability to set environment variables as well as read them. The gem reads a `config/application.yml` file and sets environment variables before anything else is configured in the Rails application.

Here’s how to use it. In your Gemfile, add:

**`gem 'figaro'`**

and run **`bundle install`**

The gem provides a generator:

**`$ bundle exec figaro install`**

The generator creates a **`config/application.yml`** file and modifies the `.gitignore file` to prevent the file from being checked into a git repository.

You can add environment variables as key/value pairs to `config/application.yml`:

```
SAMPLE_APP_DATABASE_USER: 'your username'
SAMPLE_APP_DATABASE_PASSWORD: '******'
```

The environment variables will be available anywhere in your application as ENV variables:

**`ENV["SAMPLE_APP_DATABASE_USER"]`**

[Here are the remaining ways you can achieve the same.](http://railsapps.github.io/rails-environment-variables.html)

Comment: I tried `<%= ENV['SAMPLE_APP_USERNAME'] %>` without creating another file and works perfectly. Maybe this means that I followed the setup guide correctly. To check, I tried hard-coding my username, it runs. Tried using wrong username, it failed to run. Tried the env variable, it run.

Comment: I'm using Ubuntu 16.04. I just followed the setup guide from gorails for Ubuntu 16.04 and followed your advice that I can just name it anything, and it works.

Comment: So I won't have to create another yml file.

Comment: good, in the sample application you might have followed one of the ways of setting the environment variables in the link I shared. that may not need a yml file

Comment: the two methods I have given are helpful if you deploy the project to live.

Comment: I experimented a little, I tried to to put a blank username and blank password and it still runs. Why is that?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/127283/discussion-between-sravan-and-jeramaedybohol).

Answer (score 4):

You can call it anything you want...

```
username: <%= ENV['CARROTS'] %>
password: <%= ENV['BEANS'] %>
```

You just have to make sure your deploy script sets the variables CARROTS and BEANS correctly.

Comment: What is a deploy script? I'm sorry, I'm really a newbie. I just followed the setup guide on this link https://gorails.com/setup/ubuntu/16.04

Comment: You need to google deployment script... it's how you deploy your code to a production environment.

Comment: How to Deploy a Rails 4 App With Git and Capistrano // Rob McLarty

Answer (score 2):

try this gem `dotenv-rails`

add this to Gemfile:

```
gem 'dotenv-rails', :groups => [:development, :test]
```

bundle it. Now create a `.env` file on your apps's directory with following content:

```
SAMPLE_APP_DATABASE_USER: "devuser"
SAMPLE_APP_DATABASE_PASSWORD: "devuser"
```

restart the server you're good to go. these variables are exported when you boot your app which you can access in your `database.yml` file

```
username: <%= ENV['SAMPLE_APP_DATABASE_USER'] %>
password: <%= ENV['SAMPLE_APP_DATABASE_PASSWORD'] %>
```

read [dotenv-rails documentation](https://github.com/bkeepers/dotenv) for more info